# Swift: SMLoginItemSetEnabled() not launching at login

Tags: swift

I am trying to launch an app automatically at login using `ServiceManagement`. The main app (`login-Item.app`) registers a launcher to the login items list, and the launcher starts the main app (2 separate targets). This is what I have:

The main app:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    let helperBundleId = "abc.loginItem-launcher"
    let ret = SMLoginItemSetEnabled(helperBundleId as CFString, true)
    //'ret' is true at this point
```

And from the launcher:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    var alreadyRunning:Bool = false
    for app in NSWorkspace.shared().runningApplications{
        if app.bundleIdentifier == "abc.login-item"{
            alreadyRunning = true
            break;
        }
    }

    if !alreadyRunning {
        let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath
        let index = path.index(path.endIndex, offsetBy:-22)
        var newPath = path.substring(to: index)
        newPath += "login-item.app"
        NSWorkspace.shared().launchApplication(newPath)
    }
    NSApp.terminate(nil)
}
```

If run on its own, the launcher successfully starts the main app. Additional configurations such as build phases,  are all done as suggested by tutorials, including [this](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/01/login-items/) one. I have also enabled the sandbox option, I sign the app using my Development identity, and run the app from the Application folder. It works as expected, but does not launch when I logout and back in again.

Answer (score 3):

First of all it's recommended to implement a checkbox for enabling/disabling the functionality.

In macOS it's pretty easy with Cocoa Bindings. Implement this method and bind it to the `value` of the checkbox.

```
let helperBundleIdentifier = "abc.loginItem-launcher"

@objc @available(OSX, deprecated: 10.10) // necessary to suppress the deprecated warning.
dynamic var startAtLogin : Bool {
  get {
    guard let jobDicts = SMCopyAllJobDictionaries( kSMDomainUserLaunchd ).takeRetainedValue() as? [[String:Any]] else { return false }
    return jobDicts.first { $0["Label"] as! String == helperBundleIdentifier } != nil
  } set {
    if !SMLoginItemSetEnabled(helperBundleIdentifier as CFString, newValue) {
      print("SMLoginItemSetEnabled failed.")
    }
  }
}
```

To resolve your issue launch Console.app and look into system.log. If there are multiple entries *Could not resolve CFBundleIdentifier specified by service...* regarding to the bundle identifier of your app make sure that the application in /Applications is the only copy. Delete all others in archives etc.

---

In the helper app this chunk of code

```
var alreadyRunning:Bool = false
for app in NSWorkspace.shared().runningApplications{
    if app.bundleIdentifier == "abc.login-item"{
        alreadyRunning = true
        break
    }
}

if !alreadyRunning {
```

can be reduced – thanks Swift – to

```
if NSRunningApplication.runningApplications(withBundleIdentifier: "abc.login-item").isEmpty { ...
```

Comment: My app _must_ run at login, the user cannot turn it off, so I will not implement a checkbox. Im not sure whether to mark this as correct, my code now works (with no changes to what i posted) but did use your advice on deleting all other archives. Did a reboot after, and success. Thank you.

Comment: New to macOS development here. I just spent a ridiculous amount of time discovering that "0.1.1" for the "Build" field causes _"Could not resolve ..."_ issues. Wish I would've known that a singe numeric value was expected!